# T-SQL: Function that returns multiple queries from a loop

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, while-loop

I am trying to create a function that receives as a parameter a start date and a date end of a period and results in a list totaled with the top 5 products sold for each month of the period.

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION top5Sales(@CurrentDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(
    WHILE(@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 5
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID,
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product.Name,
                MONTH(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) as 'Month',
                YEAR(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) as 'Year',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty) as 'Total Quantity Sold',
                AVG(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice) as 'Average Unit Price',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPriceDiscount) as 'Total Discount',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal) as 'Total Value Sold'
            FROM
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
            INNER JOIN
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
            ON
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
            INNER JOIN
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product
            ON
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product.ProductID = AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
            WHERE
                MONTH(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) = month(@CurrentDate) 
                and
                YEAR(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) = year(@CurrentDate)
            GROUP BY
                    AdventureWorks.Production.Product.Name,
                    AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID,
                    MONTH(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate),
                    YEAR(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate)
            ORDER BY
                [Total Quantity Sold] DESC
            SET
                @CurrentDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @CurrentDate)
        END
)
```

In fact, the above code is wrong. It serves only to exemplify the problem and give the path to some possible solution.

You do not have to follow that line of thinking. If there is another more interesting solution to this problem, feel free to expose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number and top 5 with ties and use single query to return this results as below: Can you check this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION top5Sales(@CurrentDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(        
    SELECT Top 5 with ties * from ( 
         SELECT 
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID,
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product.Name,
                MONTH(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) as 'Month',
                YEAR(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) as 'Year',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty) as 'Total Quantity Sold',
                AVG(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice) as 'Average Unit Price',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPriceDiscount) as 'Total Discount',
                SUM(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal) as 'Total Value Sold'
            FROM
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
            INNER JOIN
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
            ON
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
            INNER JOIN
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product
            ON
                AdventureWorks.Production.Product.ProductID = AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
            WHERE
                AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate > @CurrentDate
                AND AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate <= @EndDate
            GROUP BY
                    AdventureWorks.Production.Product.Name,
                    AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID,
                    MONTH(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate),
                    YEAR(AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate)
        --  ORDER BY
        --      [Total Quantity Sold] DESC
        ) a 
        Order by Row_Number() over(Partition by [ProductId], [Name], [Year], [Month] order by [Total Quantity Sold] Desc
 )
```

Comment: In fact, your solution is very good. However, it is returning only the first best-selling product during the period rather than the top five best-selling products. But his line of thought was excellent, thank you very much.

Comment: Yep we need to use ProductId, Name in the Partition by

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly, can you check?

Comment: The query is now returning in descending order of sold item, throughout the date range, organized by product name.

Comment: That is what u require correct? Based on ur query u need top 5 total quantity sold for given product, year and month wise

Comment: I am trying to create a function that receives as a parameter a start date and a date end of a period and results in a list "totaled with the top 5 products sold for each month of the period".

Comment: For example, for the first month of the established period, the five best-selling items were Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5. For the second month items were Item2, Item3, Item5, Item1, Item4.

Answer (score -1):

I checked the AdventureWorks database and I didn't see a Date table. For a basic overview, you can checkout this video - https://www.brentozar.com/training/t-sql-level/3-number-date-tables-10m/

The following logic wouldn't be in an inline-table function, but it's a fast and simple way of SELECTing the data you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(Max), 
        @CurrentDate DATETIME = '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000', 
        @EndDate DATETIME = '2008-08-31 00:00:00.000';

SELECT @sql = COALESCE( @sql + CHAR(13) + 'UNION' + CHAR(13), '') + 
              ' SELECT TOP 5 ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Year]) + ' AS [Year], ' 
                               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Month]) + ' AS [Month],
                               sod.ProductId, 
                               SUM(sod.OrderQty) AS Sales
                FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
                JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
                ON sod.SalesOrderId = soh.SalesOrderId
                    AND YEAR(soh.OrderDate) = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Year]) + '
                    AND MONTH(soh.OrderDate) = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Month]) + '
                GROUP BY sod.ProductId'
FROM dbo.[Date]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @CurrentDate AND @EndDate

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

If you execute this T-SQL you'll find it's very fast and scalable relative to other methods of getting the same data.

Comment: No don't do this.  Dynamic SQL is hard to read, relatively expensive to parse, error prone and potentially a security flaw.  You should only use it when you absolutely have to, and in this case you don't.

Comment: A cursory glance at the GROUP BY clause indicates this isn't going to do what the OP is looking for. Even if it did, this would be a downvote as there is no reason to use dynamic sql and sp_executesql